# C++: Checking to see if paranthesis and brackets are balanced in a string (Logic question)

Tags: c++, logic

Check the string if every '(' in it is met by either ')', or '{'.
Check the string if every '{' in it is met by either '}', or '('.

You can never have string like this "a(a{a)a}a" for example, but a string like this "a(a{a}a)a" is okay.
Additionally, all opening parenthesis and opening curly brackets must have a matching closing pair.

The function will return true if balanced, or false if not. Been stumped on this for the past few hours.

Comment: can you also share the source (as a public link of the same) of this question, just to make sure it is not a part of an ongoing contest.

Comment: Read about stacks.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the string, push() the character in a [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) if it's an opening bracket. If it's a closing bracket check the top() of your stack and pop() if it's the associated opening bracket, or return false otherwise.